# Is there an autoremove feature for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

So, I have more experience with Linux than I do with PowerShell.  I saw the recent upgrade to PowerShell came out and I went ahead and installed it.

I have Windows PowerShell 5.1 installed, but I don't want to mess with that.  I have Microsoft PowerShell v7.3.3 installed, that's the version that I would like to remove.

Then there is the version that I just upgraded to, which was Microsoft PowerShell 7.3.4, which I guess came out either this morning, or maybe last night, I don't know.

Anyway, In Linux, there is a handy feature called "AutoRemove." Ex. sudo dnf autoremove.  It removes the old version of Linux after it installs the updated version.

I was wondering if PowerShell has a feature like this, that would remove the old Microsoft PowerShell v7.3.3, now that i have 7.3.4 installed. I just consider having v7.3.3 on my system a waste of hard drive space.

please let me clarify (because i already saw this question on here) i am not trying to remove windows powershell v5.1 because i know that it is necessary for windows to function properly. the version that i am trying to remove is the 7.3.3 version.

Anyone out there have any suggestions, or advice on this topic.  Thanks so much for all of your answers in advance.

Comment: Windows dosen't really have an apt style package manager. Even the official one just runs the same installers you do. For Minor versions pretty sure the new one just overwrites the old one for things like PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

#### I have 7.3.3 installed, how do I remove it?

If you have already installed 7.3.4 then there is no need to remove 7.3.3 as it *should* have already been removed.

If you really want to remove 7.3.3 then run the 7.3.3 installer again. The options displayed include repairing or removing it:

- Click "Next"

  [image]
- Click "Remove"

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you see both PowerShell versions 7.3.3 and 7.3.4 in
*Control Panel > Programs and Features*, then you may remove version
7.3.3 from there.

If you only see one version, then the installation of 7.3.4 has only
upgraded version 7.3.3, and you don't need to uninstall everything.

Otherwise, the brute-force method is to uninstall PowerShell 7 and
install PowerShell 7.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

[image: PowerShell in Windows "features"]

In *Control panel > All Control Panel Items > Programs and Features*, in the *Turn Windows features on or off* dialog, select the appropriate version of PowerShell and remove it.